# Need to split string into vector with delimiter

Tags: c++, string, vector

The following code is supposed to split a string with delimiters using a function.

Given the following function declaration:

```
vector<string> split(string target, string delimiter);
```

I need to implement the function so that it returns a vector of substrings in `target` that are separated by the string `delimiter`. For example:

```
split("10,20,30", ",")
```

should return a `vector` with the strings "10", "20", and "30". Similarly,

```
split("do re mi fa so la ti do", " ")
```

should return a `vector` with the strings "do", "re", "mi", "fa", "so", "la", "ti", and "do".

My code only outputs the first element of the `vector`. I don't see anything wrong with the function implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> split(string, string);

int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    string target;
    string delim;
    split(target, delim);
    v = split(target, delim);
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        cout << v[i] << " ";
}

vector<string> split(string target, string delim)
{
    cout << "Enter string: "<< endl;
    getline(cin, target);
    cout << "Enter delimiter:" << endl;
    getline(cin, delim);
    vector<string> v;
    size_t x = target.find(delim);
    while (x!= string::npos) {
        v.push_back(target.substr(0,x));
        target = target.substr(x);
        x = target.find(delim);
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Something is obviously wrong with the posted code's balance of `{` vs `}`, which would be clear if you reasonably indented. Your uncontested `return` is embedded *inside* your `while` loop. Meaning: only one iteration will ever take place.

Comment: The answer to this question is: use a debugger.

Comment: `split(target, delim);` `v = split(target, delim);` Explain to your nearest rubber duck why you need both of these lines.

Comment: When you convince your duck that you need both (or he convinces you otherwise), explain why `split` needs parameters `target` and `delim`. What will happen if I call `split("1:2:3", ":")`? What will happen if I call `split("a b c", " ")`? What will happen if I call `split("", "")`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> split(string, string);

int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    string target;
    string delim;

    cout << "Enter string: "<< endl;
    getline(cin, target);
    cout << "Enter delimiter:" << endl;
    getline(cin, delim);

    v = split(target, delim);
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        cout << v[i] << " ";
}

vector<string> split(string target, string delim)
{
    vector<string> v;
    if (!target.empty()) {
        string::size_type start = 0, found, length;
        do {
            found = target.find(delim, start);
            if (found == string::npos)
                break;

            length = found - start;
            v.push_back(target.substr(start, length));
            start += (length + delim.size());
        }
        while (true);

        v.push_back(target.substr(start));            
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: There is a typo above: the first line of the do-while statement should be `size_t x = target.find(start, delim);`

Comment: @EB2127 I think you meant `size_t x = target.find(delim, start);` instead. I have fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I copied the line without correcting it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> split(string target, string delimiter)
{
    vector<string> components;
    if (!target.empty())
    {
         size_t start = 0;
         do
         {
             const size_t index = target.find(delimiter, start);
             if (index == string::npos)
             {
                 break;
             }
             const size_t length = index - start;
             components.push_back(target.substr(start, length));
             start += (length + delimiter.size());
         } while (true);
         components.push_back(target.substr(start));
    }

    return components;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stack overflow.  I wanted to add a comment saying start += delim.size(); is wrong but I could not add a comment because my reputation is too low.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Now the Community bot says my answer is unclear.  Do I need a main or something besides a working split function?  Do I need to add "Try this" before the code?  I'm confused.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).